# Perl PPM error "failed 500 Can't connect to ppm4.activestate.com:8080 (connect: timeout)"

Tags: perl, activestate

when I try to connect PPM it shows this error, i have verified firewall also it has not activated. I can't able to download even a single module from activestate.

Thanks in advance.

Arivu

Comment: Are you able to connect via telnet? it may be a tranative error at the server side, or there could be something blocking your connection in between. Either way, it's not really a programming question, but more of a support issue, and seems a little off topic for this website.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a proxy, it could be that you have not set the proxy environment variable.

```
 set http_proxy=http://myproxyserver.mydomain.com:5050
```

See [their PPM Documenation](http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.12/faq/ActivePerl-faq2.html#ppm_and_proxies)

Answer (score 0):

Install Fiddler Web Debugger ([www.fiddler2.com](http://www.fiddler2.com)), launch it, start a web browser (for Fiddle to detect settings), then relaunch PPM.

Fiddler will work as the proxy and resolve the requests properly.  I didn't even need to add the "http_proxy" environment setting that is recommended by ActiveState, but you may need to, so from a command prompt type: `set http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8888` then from this same command prompt type `PPM` to launch the PPM